# Show and close dynamically created dialog in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, popupwindow

I have scenarios which are created dynamically by clicking *Add Scenario* button. Initially 1 scenario will be there and then user can add 4 scenarios. Maximum 5 scenarios can be added. Each scenario has a calculator icon and by clicking it, it will show a calculator popup.

If user clicks calculator icon on a particular scenario, it should show only particular scenario's calculator popup; and if user clicks close, it should close the popup.

I'm passing `scenarios.Id` in `showCalculatorPopup(scenarios.Id)` and `CloseCalculatorPopup(scenarios.Id)` and with scenarios.Id i'm trying to open and close particular scenario's popup.

My issue is if I click a calculator icon in scenario 1, popup is being opened in all scenarios. I tried using `eval(), window[]` to no avail.

**Updated the code.**

Instead of Switch Case i'm using

```
vm.showCalculatorPopup = function (ScenarioId) {
    vm['calculatorPopup' + ScenarioId] = true;
}
```

Added `break;`. Even after adding break it's not working properly. When i open and close calculator for 1st time in scenario 1 then its working fine.
But when i add scenario 2 and click calculator icon, its shows the popup and when i click close in scenario 1 popup it close the scenario 2 popup.

Can't use index because button is inside the `Licenceplates` and its inside the `Sections` and its inside the `Scenarios`.

```
<div data-ng-app="ang" data-ng-controller="InputController as input">

    <div data-ng-repeat="scenarios in input.model.Scenarios">        <!-- Scenario Id = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 -->
        <div data-ng-repeat="sections in scenarios.Sections">
            <div data-ng-repeat="licensePlates in sections.LicensePlates">

                <button data-ng-click="input.showCalculatorPopup(scenarios.Id)">Calculate</button>
                <div data-ng-show="input.calculatorPopup{{scenarios.Id}}">
                    Dialog Box
                    <button data-ng-click="input.CloseCalculatorPopup(scenarios.Id)"></button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Latest Angular Controller

```
vm.showCalculatorPopup = function (ScenarioId) {
       vm['calculatorPopup' + ScenarioId] = true; 
}

vm.showCalculatorPopup = function (ScenarioId) {
       vm['calculatorPopup' + ScenarioId] = false; 
}
```

Previous Angular Controller

```
vm.showCalculatorPopup = function (ScenarioId) {

    vm.eval('calculatorPopup' + ScenarioId) = true;
    // or
    vm.window['calculatorPopup' + ScenarioId] = true;
    vm.calculatorPopup1 = true; // working

    // or

    switch (ScenarioId) {
        case 1:
            vm.calculatorPopup1 = true;
            break;
        case 2:
            vm.calculatorPopup2 = true;
            break;
        case 3:
            vm.calculatorPopup3 = true;
            break;
        case 4:
            vm.calculatorPopup4 = true;
            break;
        case 5:
            vm.calculatorPopup5 = true;
            break;
    }
}

vm.CloseCalculatorPopup = function (ScenarioId) {
    switch (ScenarioId) {
        case 1:
            vm.calculatorPopup1 = false;
            break;
        //case 3 ,4 
        case 5:
            vm.calculatorPopup2 = false;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to create directive in such scenarios

Answer (score 0):

Your `switch` cases are never breaking, so you are executing every later case.

```
switch (ScenarioId) {
        case 1:
            vm.calculatorPopup1 = true;
            break;
        case 2:
            vm.calculatorPopup2 = true;
            break;
        case 3:
            vm.calculatorPopup3 = true;
            break;
        case 4:
            vm.calculatorPopup4 = true;
            break;
        case 5:
            vm.calculatorPopup5 = true;
            break;
    }
```

You have the same problem with the other `swtich`. [More info on this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp).

Comment: Thanks. Can i use vm.eval('calculatorPopup' + ScenarioId) = true; like this?

Comment: This should do it: vm['calculatorPopup' + ScenarioId] = true;

Answer (score 0):

you could pass $index instead of scenarios.Id.  finally you need to add a break statement in your switch statements

```
    switch (ScenarioId) {
    case 1:
        vm.calculatorPopup1 = true;
        break;
    case 2:
        vm.calculatorPopup2 = true;
        break;
    case 3:
        vm.calculatorPopup3 = true;
        break;
    case 4:
        vm.calculatorPopup4 = true;
        break;
    case 5:
        vm.calculatorPopup5 = true;
        break;
   }
}

vm.CloseCalculatorPopup = function (ScenarioId) {
  switch (ScenarioId) {
      case 1:
         vm.calculatorPopup1 = false;
         break;
    case 2:
        vm.calculatorPopup2 = false;
        break; 
 }
}
```

break stops the evaluation of your switch statement.

Comment: Thanks. Can i use vm.eval('calculatorPopup' + ScenarioId) = true; like this?